# Java, MySQL, spring application

Tags: java, mysql

I’m a trying to develop a attendance application which uses smart phone to update user attendance. 
I’m developing backend service in java using spring framework, my application works in this way 
1. A new user is created by a admin and a default password is given to all user.
2. The user uses the credentials given by admin to signin

The mobile application fetch the mobile imei number at first login of the user

My question is what is based way to store imei number to MySQL database so that the program checks whether the user is using same mobile to update their attendance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be save the details in  a table with along with UserId/Username then later you can  cache the IMEI value with UserId/Username as a key reference, which would save alot of I/O overhead.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like you are looking to build some sort of authentication with the mobile IMEI number and not email id.

You could be using JWT tokens and send them over to verify the user.

I would suggest : 
1) send the IMEI over the first time and create a JWT token using that IMEI as a key. 
2) return the token and just store the token in the local storage of the mobile. 
3) Everytime a request is made make sure to evaluate that the token is sent and the token is not modified by verifying the imei and token hash.

https://jwt.io/introduction/